# Masory.js (for html grid). How to customise to regrid divs on #container resize by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masonry

[masonry site](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

[masonry.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.2.2/masonry.pkgd.js)

The masonry.js plug in works fine on window resize (it re-grid the divs well)
but I need it to re-grid when I press a button that resize the #container div. While the screen screen resolution is still same.

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({  columnWidth: 200,  itemSelector: '.item'});

$container.masonry('bindResize')//resize on window resize
```

//=========================

```
eventie.bind( '#resize_button', 'click', function() {
// 
  document.getElementById('#container').style.width='70%';
//...................................
//       do the rearrangement 
//...................................
  }
```

Comment: document.getElementById('container') ... No #.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger masonry's `layout()` method after you change the width of the container.

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/348rvdb0/1/)

JSCODE

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
    var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
        columnWidth: 60
    });

    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        $('.masonry').css('width', '50%');
        msnry.layout();
    })

});
```